# Trying To Find A Android Dependencies Version List

Tags: android

Hello I am trying to find a list of gradle dependencies for android,my problem is I want to use the latest version of the dependencies, the google tutorials have the recyclerview dependency as 23.0.1, and I know there are later versions such as 23.2.1 etc. I know what maven is however I can't find certain things, like com.android.support:design:23.1.0 etc.Is there a central repository? .. any help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The android support library dependencies you mention are not part of an external maven repo.  They are actually stored in your hard drive in the Android SDK.  You do not need to know their location. Since the android gradle plugin knows where they are.

If you want the latest libraries, run the Android updater tool and make sure you get the latest "Android Support Library" version (as well as everything else).

Comment: Do I need to still add them through gradle if I download the support library? if so how would I know which version is the latest?

Comment: The gradle dependencies are still required.  There are valid cases when you don't want to be forced to upgrade, so the android plugin will not force you to change. Android Studio will tell you when they get out of date after a new version is downloaded using the updater too - they will be highlighted yellow with an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

**Support Library Setup**

Downloading the Support Libraries

> The Android Support Library package is provided as a supplemental
>   download to the Android SDK and is available through the Android SDK
>   Manager. Follow the instructions below to obtain the Support Library
>   files.

**To download the Support Library through the SDK Manager:**

- Start the Android SDK Manager.
- In the SDK Manager window, scroll to the end of the Packages list,
  find the Extras folder and, if necessary, expand to show its
  contents.
- Select the Android Support Library item.
- Note: If you're developing with Android Studio, select and install
  the Android Support Repository item instead.

Click the Install packages... button.

check this [Support Library Setup](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html) and check [SDK Tools Release Notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/sdk-tools.html)

Comment: links are broken. Use these: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html and https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/sdk-tools.html